# Сообщение о необходимости установки разрешений

Tags: java, android-studio, permissions

При установке моего приложения никак не получается с выведением сообщения о необходимости установки разрешения, выскакивает стандартное сообщение об ошибке  программы. Есть ли способ выдать своё сообщение поверх или вместо всплывающего сообщения об ошибке? У меня получается выводить и Toast и AlertDialog, только если необходим EXTERNAL_STORAGE, но при доступе к камере и микрофону всё таки вылезало сообщение об ошибке, которое убивало все мои попытки. Да, мне не нужно стандартные выведения окон с галочками о подтверждении разрешений, а просто вывести напоминание.

Comment: Нужно больше информации приведите пример ваших разрешений описаных в манифесте. На каком устройстве тестируете?

Comment: С 6 версии ОС разрешения нужно запрашивать в рантайме, через стандартный системный диалог. Иначе сделать нельзя. Если их не запросить - приложение будет падать.

Comment: if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

        } else { ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
                },
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);}